# Modify regex to allow underscore

Tags: regex

I'm using this regex to check if a username contains space or chars.

```
/\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\Z/
```

By the way I want to allow underscore. How can I do?

Comment: `if a username contains space` You are not checking if it contains space, you are checking if it contains word chars. Not word characters could be punctuation, brackets or spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `_` in character class:

```
/\A[_a-zA-Z0-9]+\Z/
```

OR better:

```
/\A\w+\Z/
```

since `\w` means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

btw you can use: `/^\w+$/` also.